# I want to convert an UPDATE INNER JOIN query from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to convert this query from MS Access to SQL Server. But I get an error

> The multi-part identifier "B.PONumber" could not be bound.

This is the MS Access query:

```
UPDATE CompStagingReturnByPO 
INNER JOIN ComponentInventory ON CompStagingReturnByPO.ReceivingID = ComponentInventory.ReceivingID 
SET ComponentInventory.PONumber = "", ComponentInventory.ReceivingID = 
[ComponentInventory]![ReceivingID] & "-EBI" 
WHERE (((CompStagingReturnByPO.Component)="bulk"));
```

And this is what I've tried for SQL Server:

```
UPDATE A 
SET B.PONumber = '', B.ReceivingID = [B].[ReceivingID] + '-EBI'
FROM CompStagingReturnByPO A
INNER JOIN ComponentInventory B ON A.ReceivingID = B.ReceivingID
WHERE (((A.Component)='bulk'));
```

But I get that error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've followed up other similar questions on stack, but they don't quite help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant set a field in `B` by running an `UPDATE` on `A`. You'll need two `update` statements.

Try this.

```
UPDATE B 
SET  B.PONumber = '', B.ReceivingID = B.ReceivingID + '-EBI' 
FROM ComponentInventory AS B
INNER JOIN CompStagingReturnByPO AS A
       ON A.ReceivingID = B.ReceivingID
WHERE A.Component='bulk';
```

I spoke to hastily when I stated that you would need two `update` statements. Since you are only changing fields in `B`, you can get away with a single `UPDATE`.

Comment: `sql-server` functions differently than `access-sql` in various ways. This includes syntax ( how you write a statement ).

Comment: Thanks edwards. Can you please show me how to make this update query twice in sql for achieving the same functionality like access? I'm quite a beginner

Comment: Good luck, I've been working in `access-sql` all week